# AvMutableComposition issues having black frame at the end

Tags: xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avmutablecomposition

I capturing a video using AVCaptureConnection in my iOS app. After that I add some images in the video as CALayers. Everything is working fine but I get a black frame at the very end of the resulting video after adding images. There is no frame of actual audio/video that has been affected in this. For audio I am extracting it and changing its pitch and then add it using AVMutableComposition. Here is the code that I am using. Please help me with what I am doing wrong or do I need to add something else.

```
cmp = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoComposition = [cmp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioComposition = [cmp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *sourceVideoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = [[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];


    [videoComposition insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil] ;
    [audioComposition insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:sourceAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    animComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    animComp.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320, 320);
    animComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,30);
    animComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer  inLayer:parentLayer];

    // to gather the audio part of the video
    NSArray *tracksToDuck = [cmp tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    NSMutableArray *trackMixArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tracksToDuck count]; i++) {
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *trackMix = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:[tracksToDuck objectAtIndex:i]];
        [trackMix setVolume:5 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        [trackMixArray addObject:trackMix];
    }
    audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    audioMix.inputParameters = trackMixArray;

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]);
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerVideoInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoComposition];

    [layerVideoInstruction setOpacity:1.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerVideoInstruction] ;
    animComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:instruction];
    [self exportMovie:self];
```

This is my method for exporting the video

```
-(IBAction) exportMovie:(id)sender{

    //successCheck = NO;
    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *tempPath = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"Temp Path: %@",tempPath);

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Final.MP4",tempPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ;
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fileName ]){
        NSError *ferror = nil ;
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:fileName error:&ferror];
    }

    NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:cmp presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality]  ;
    exporter.outputURL = exportURL;
    exporter.videoComposition = animComp;
    //exporter.audioMix = audioMix;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
        switch (exporter.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:{
                NSLog(@"Fail");
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:{
                NSLog(@"Success video");
                                });
                break;
            }

            default:
                break;
        }
           }];
    NSLog(@"outside");
}
```

Comment: In which part did you change the pitch? I am looking to change the pitch of exported audio but am having some trouble...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a property of exportsession to give the time range ,
try giving time range little less than the actual time (few nano seconds less)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the true video duration from AVAssetTrack. The duration of AVAsset is sometimes longer than AVAssetTrack' one.

Check durations out like this.

```
print(asset.duration.seconds.description)
print(videoTrack.timeRange.duration.description)
```

So you can change this line.

```
[videoComposition insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil] ;
```

To like this.

```
 [videoComposition insertTimeRange:sourceVideoTrack.timeRange, ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil] ;
```

For swift 5

```
videoComposition.insertTimeRange(sourceVideoTrack.timeRange, of: sourceVideoTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
```

Then you will avoid the last black frame :)

Hope this helps someone still suffer.

Comment: This is absolutely whats happening in my case.  Thanks for brining this to my attention ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to write this for people with my specific issue.

I was taking a video and trying to speed it up / slow it down by taking an `AVMutableComposition` and scaling the time range of the audio and video components via `scaleTimeRange`

Scaling the time range to 2x speed or 3x speed sometimes caused the last few frames of the video to be black. Fortunately, @Khushboo's answer fixed my problem as well.

However, instead of decreasing the exporter's timeRange by a few nanoseconds, I just made it the same as the composition's duration which ended up working perfectly.

```
exporter?.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: composition.duration)
```

Hope this helps!